# How FB graph api 2.0 replace FQL like this?

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

As we all know, facebook release the big updated on 30th April,2014. One of the changes log or alert is, FQL will not be available for the next version.

I tried and tried hard to replace and existing FQL using the graph API in order to get the same result. However, I failed.

One of the example goes like this:

```
SELECT src_big, caption, object_id, owner, images, created
     FROM photo WHERE aid IN
        (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE
           owner IN (page_id1, page_id2, page_id3, page_id4)
           AND type!='profile'
           ORDER BY modified DESC)
        AND created < 1398172643
        ORDER BY created DESC
        LIMIT 16
```

This example is to get some public photos from pages.

Anyone can tell me, how can I do that with Open Graph?